# Multiple color for a bar(yAxis) using echart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I want to make a bar-chart like this using [ECHARTS](https://echarts.apache.org/) :

[image]

I have tried using their [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-simple), but I don't find any [option](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar) to make it multiple colors.

I got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173050/3835843), it is not useful to make a bar multiple colors.

I have very little knowledge about eCharts. Can anybody give me any reference how can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have different colors for each series in the stacked bar? Just draw imaginary vertical line across all series value and set color style for all crossing values.

```js
{
          name: 'Series-1',
          type: 'bar',
          stack: '1',
          data: [5, { value: 20, itemStyle: { color: 'blue'} }, 36, 10, 10, 20]
      },{
          name: 'Series-2',
          type: 'bar',
          stack: '1',
          data: [5, {value: 20, itemStyle: { color: 'green'} }, 36, 10, 10, 20]
      }
```

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
  var option = {
      title: {
          text: 'ECharts'
      },
      tooltip: {},
      legend: {
          data:['Label']
      },
      xAxis: {
          data: ["Category1","Category2","Category3","Category4","Category5","Category6"]
      },
      yAxis: {},
      series: [{
          name: 'Series-1',
          type: 'bar',
          stack: '1',
          data: [5, { value: 20, itemStyle: { color: 'blue'} }, 36, 10, 10, 20]
      },{
          name: 'Series-2',
          type: 'bar',
          stack: '1',
          data: [5, {value: 20, itemStyle: { color: 'green'} }, 36, 10, 10, 20]
      }
      ]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.7.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: In my case, some bar needs only one color. Say, in your example if I want to make Category3 bar only yellow color, how can I do that?

Comment: If you imagine a matrix of values where normal bar use one row by horizontal then stack use one row by vertical. If you want to get stack bar with single color then you need to set for value of each series by vertical this color.

Comment: In my example above you need to change blue to green and you get desired.

Comment: Yes. I got it. If I face any issue I will get back to you.