# How to apply different linear gradient for each bar in echarts bar series?

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, data-visualization, echarts

Right now i can apply same gradient to all bars but I need to apply linear gradient color to each bar based on a value. i.e first bar with gradient from color1 to color2 and second bar can be gradient from color1 to color3. I have gone through the docs but couldn't find the necessary info .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's easy.

[image]

In the bar series you have the [option to define style](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.data.itemStyle) for each datapoint. Please take a look on the [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62062890/1597964). In you case all is the same but solid color changes to our gradient.

For control gradients and his colors you need to use something like this:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
var graphic = echarts.graphic;

var barData = [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20];
var barColors = [
  ['rgba(176,196,222, 0.3)', 'rgba(176,196,222, 1)'],
  ['rgba(220,20,60, 0.3)', 'rgba(220,20,60, 1)'],
  ['rgba(189,183,107, 0.3)', 'rgba(189,183,107, 1)'],
  ['rgba(47,79,79, 0.3)', 'rgba(47,79,79, 1)'],
  ['rgba(30,144,255, 0.3)', 'rgba(30,144,255, 1)'],
  ['rgba(112,128,144, 0.3)', 'rgba(112,128,144, 1)'],
];
var chartData = seriesData(barData, barColors);

function seriesData(data, colors) {
  return data.map((val, idx) => {
    return {
      value: val,
      itemStyle: {
        color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [{
            offset: 0,
            color: colors[idx][0]
          },
          {
            offset: 1,
            color: colors[idx][1]
          }
        ])
      }
    }
  })
}

var option = {
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.8.0/dist/echarts.min.js'></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```